# Kubernetes Egress Network Policy is not working on a pod selected

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, weave

I'm facing a weird issue on setting up egress network policy on my kube cluster.

Basically I want my pod A to access only pod B.

I have two pods:

1. hello-k8s-deploy
2. nginx

The hello-k8s-deploy pod expose an API on port `8080` via NodePort.
My nginx pod is simply an image to access the API.

So let's try logging in to the nginx pod and access that API exposed by the hello-k8s-deploy pod.

[image]

Above shows that the API responded back with message starts with `Hello K8s!`

Now let's apply the network policy on my nginx pod so it can access only this API, nothing else.

**Network policy:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: app
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx
  egress:
    - to:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: hello-k8s-deploy
  policyTypes:
   - Egress
```

Above policy will be applied to pod with label `run: nginx`

And the rule is allow traffic to pod with label  `app: hello-k8s-deploy`

Let's validate it by looking at the definition of both of the pods nginx and hello-k8s-deploy

**nginx:**

[image]

**hello-k8s-deploy**

[image]

As we can see both labels are matching the Network policy.

After I applied the network policy and access the nginx again I expect to work the same and get a response from the API but I'm getting the below error.

[image]

**Take note that:**

1. All of the resources are in the same namespace `app`
2. My network addon is weave-net which has support for network policy as per documentation.
3. I even tried to specify the namespace selector and add port 8080.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue, basically the problem I was getting is `could not resolve host hello-k8s-svc`. It means k8s is trying to connect using this host and resolving through dns name (service name).

And since my pod is only allowing egress to hello-k8s-deploy, it's failing as it also needs to connect to kube-dns for resolving the dns. So before you apply an egress make sure the pod or all pods in your namespace are allowing to connect to kube-dns for dns resolution.

The fix is simply creating an egress resource to all pods to connect to kube-dns on top of your pod specific egress configuration.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          networking/namespace: kube-system
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: kube-dns
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

In my case I labeled the kube-system namespace:

```
 kubectl label namespace kube-system networking/namespace=kube-system
```